# Android Java Random math division keep showing "divide by zero"

Tags: java, android, math, random, divide-by-zero

I'm trying to create an app that will generate random operands questions by using a switch case.

```
        MaxDigit = Difficulty.Level;
    Random RandomNumber = new Random();

    //Set the First and Second Number to Random Number
    FNumber = RandomNumber.nextInt(MaxDigit);
    SNumber = RandomNumber.nextInt(MaxDigit);


    Random OperandsChoise = new Random();
    int Operands = OperandsChoise.nextInt(4);

    if ((FNumber / SNumber) >= 1) {
        switch (Operands){

            case 0 :
                this.Answer = this.FNumber + this.SNumber;
                this.QTyoe = FNumber + "+" + SNumber + "=";
                break;

            case 1 :
                this.Answer = this.FNumber - this.SNumber;

                this.QTyoe = FNumber + "-" + SNumber + "=";
                break;

            case 2 :
                this.Answer = this.FNumber * this.SNumber;

                this.QTyoe = FNumber + "*" + SNumber + "=";
                break;

            case 3 :
                this.Answer = (this.FNumber +2) / (this.SNumber +1);

                this.QTyoe = FNumber + "/" + SNumber + "=";
                break;
        }
    }
```

The MaxDigit is getting integers from another activity called "Difficulty" to let users decide how hard the math question they want to challenge (Easy-9, Medium-99, Hard-999). But somehow the SNumber keeps getting 0 and cashing crash.

Is there any way to set SNumber within the range and make the Answer will not less than 1?

Comment: Well what is the value of `MaxDigit`? If you want a random number excluding 1 you can just add 1 to your generated number. I would also recommend taking note of Java naming conventions, variables should be in `camelCase`, generally only class names should be in `PascalCase`.

Comment: `Random.nextInt(N)` return number from interval `[0, N)` ... to return from interval `[1, N)` you need to select from `[0, N-1)` and add `1` ... [information about braces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_(mathematics)#Including_or_excluding_endpoints)

Comment: @HenryTwist The value of `MaxDigit` will change depending on user difficulty level selection (9, 99, 999). Import from another Activity

Comment: @Selvin But I need to import the Maxdigit on other activities, to let users select the difficulty level. I have tried using method like (MaxDigit, MaxDigit+1) and (0, MaxDigit+1) but none of these works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see from your code that both `FNumber` and `SNumber` will always be positive. You can clamp the second number to never be smaller than 0, for example:

```
SNumber = RandomNumber.nextInt(MaxDigit - 1) + 1;
```

The snippet above will ensure that `SNumber` will never be greater than `MaxDigit` while always being greater than or equal to 1.